Perl - semicolon in a password for DB connection makes app fail
Our Perl app which is compiled as exe do following:

read lot of params from ini file (including dbname+username+password)
connect to db with specified params and do some maintenance work

Problem: recently admin changed password on server and new password contains ";" (semicolon) char. That make Perl app always fail on attempt to connect DB2 database.
So, it looks a bit weird when shell scripts works fine, win32 app works fine, .net components works fine with new password. But only this Perl executable always fail to connect db2 db.
I made a small experiment - set the same password on our local staging environment and I see exactly the same effect - shell scripts and win32 app works fine but only Perl app fail.
Then I replaced semicolon in password with "-" and now Perl app works fine (all other apps and scripts also works fine with any password values).
Thus, it looks like the problem is exactly with ";" char in a password for Perl app!
Info about Perl app:

this is Windows platform (and Db2 is 11.1.47)
This is perl, v5.8.8 built for MSWin32-x86-multi-thread
PerlApp 6.0.2 build 203380
used packages:

Config::IniFiles 2.52 - http://search.cpan.org/dist/Config-IniFiles-2.52/
DBI 1.58 - http://search.cpan.org/dist/DBI-1.58/
DBD::DB2 1.79 - http://search.cpan.org/dist/DBD-DB2-1.79/



Please note: I added debug output to our Perl app and I confirm that password string passed into a call to DBI-connect is 100% valid. So, value with semicolon was correctly loaded from ini-file and seems it fail somewhere inside DBI-connect.
Just FYI:
Piece of code used to connect db:
$pdbh = DBI->connect($dsn, $init::user, $init::passwd);

Error message we got:
DBI connect('Txxxx','build',...) failed: [IBM][CLI Driver] SQL30082N  Security processing failed with reason "24" ("USERNAME AND/OR PASSWORD INVALID").  SQLSTATE=08001

Questions are:

Is it possible to mask semicolon char in a string value to make DBI (or DBD::DB2 ?) module connect db2 database correctly even with semicolon in a password?
In a theory - what could be wrong with a string with semicolon inside a function like DBI-connect(...) ?
What other characters in a string value could cause problems when calling Perl functions?


Have you tried to escape ; with \ ?

Good point. I just tried - to escape with "", to enclose whole password with single or double quotes, to enclose password with {...} - NO WAY! All attempts fail. Error is the same in all cases - as described in a question. :-\

The DB2 docs say that you can't have a semicolon in a DB2 password.
I'm not a DB2 user, but from what I've read it seems the literal ; is reserved for the connection string format. Everything after the semicolon are various connection settings. This means that your password is effectively truncated.

Thank you. That is very interesting. So, practically it means that when I use semicolon in a password for windows user then I can connect db from shell script (because this shell command works fine - "db2 connect to Txxxx user build using Kds+2]$Z1;eW@7h") but all external drivers (ODBC, OleDB, Ado.Net, DBI) will not be able to connect such db.
